# Trying a practice program from codechef. My code has 4 variables, but the console does not accept the 4th value

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying a beginner program as a practice.
Link to og question: https://www.codechef.com/problems/COOK82A

I am new to java, learnt its basics from school curriculum. I have used 4 variables (v, v1, v2, v3) to take inputs for scores from the user, but as i enter the 4th value it displays the result(which is evaluated only after the 4 values are taken).

[image: CODE image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Need a bit more context, are you seeing any errors?  Also code snippets are preferred over screen shots as I can quickly copy and paste.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that users relying on screen readers can't see code posted as an image, and search engines can't find it. Please edit your question with your code as text.

Answer (score 0):

Use a print statement or the debugger to see what's in v.  My guess is it may be "1."  nextInt may not move you past that line and then the first call to nextLine is getting that line.  You may need to have a throw away nextLine right before you ask the user for input to clear the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `sc.nextLine();` after line 11. This is because the hard return is not taken by the `.nextInt()` method, so the hard return is read in when you are entering the strings.